# JS libraries and frameworks standard directories

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, directory-structure

In a web app, libraries are in directories like these:

```
/lib
/library
/libraries
```

/lib, /library, /libraries are de facto standards. Now,

- where should we locate JS libraries? (e.g. jQuery)
- where should we locate JS frameworks? (e.g. Backbone.js, Knockout.js, Ember.js, Angular.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really up to you.

In a Django webapp, for example, it makes sense to keep these files in the STATIC_FILES dir specified by your settings file, because they are downloaded by clients and should be served statically.

Then you may want to have a versioning system for these files based on filename or directory name, so that you can instruct your HTTP server to set proper expiry headers.

There is a fundamental difference here from /lib in a C project, because these are files that are served to clients and should be able to be cache-busted at any time.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I put third-party libraries and frameworks (I don't really see a need to distinguish between them) in a directory called `/vendor`.  I prefer putting it there because it clearly separates libraries we have written (which naturally go in `/lib`) from unmodified vendor libraries (a.k.a. dependencies).

One thing to consider is that a lot of libraries (Bootstrap, for example) come with more than just JavaScript: there's CSS and images too.  Nothing annoys me more than a third-party library that wants to put its CSS in my root `/css`, images in my root `/img`, etc.  I want all those dependencies kept together.  So my directory structure looks something like this:

```
/
   lib/
       mylib.js
   css/
       mycss.css
   img/
       myimg.png
   vendor/
       jquery-1.10.0.min.js
       bootstrap/
           img/
               bootstrapglphs.png
           css/
               bootstrapcss.css
```